# Angular 4 and RxJS 5: Observable.concat() behaving unexpectedly

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

My Angular 4 / TypeScript 2.3 service has a function `build()` that errors if a class property isn't initialized. I'm trying to build a safer version -- `safeBuild()` -- that will return an Observable that will wait and listen for the property to be initialized before trying to call `build()`

```
export class BuildService {
  
  renderer:Renderer2; // must be set for build() below to work
  
  // emits the new Renderer2 when renderer is set
  private rendererSet$:BehaviorSubject<Renderer2> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  /** Set renderer, and notify any listener */
  setRenderer(renderer:Renderer2){
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.rendererSet$.next(renderer);
  }

  /** Returns a new DOM element. Requires renderer to be set */
  build(elemTag:string){
    // if renderer is not set, we can't proceed
    // why is this error thrown when safeBuild() is called?
    if (!this.renderer) 
      throw new Error('Renderer must be set before build() is run');

    return this.renderer.createElement(elemTag);
  }

  /**
   * A safe version of build(). Will wait until renderer is set
   * before attempting to call build (Asynchronous)
   */
  safeBuild(elemTag:string):Observable<any> {
    // inform user that renderer should be set
    // this warning is printed to the console as expected
    if (!this.renderer) 
      console.warn('The build will be delayed until setRenderer() is called');

    // Listen to rendererSet$, filter out the null output, and call build()
    // only once the renderer is set. Why does the error still get thrown?
    return Observable.concat(
      this.rendererSet$.filter(e=>!!e).take(1),
      Observable.of(this.build(elemTag))
    )
  }
}
```

I try to build like this (from another service):

```
this.buildService.safeBuild(elemTag).subscribe(...)
```

In the console I see:

> Warn: The build will be delayed until setRenderer() is called
>
> Error: Renderer must be set before build() is run

I expected the warning, but then nothing to happen until another part of my app calls `setRenderer()`. At that point, the code in `subscribe()` would run.

Why do I see the error?

Comment: When do you call setRenderer?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner later  -- after `safeBuild()`, and from another component.

Comment: `Observable.of(this.build(elemTag))` needs to call `this.build` to create the observable, which happens *before* passing it to `.concat`.

Comment: Why not just `return this.rendererSet$.filter(e => !!e).map(() => this.build());`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe close to the solution I came to on my own. I kept `take(1)` because I don't want the burden to unsubscribe to be on the calling code, and I used `switchMap(r => Observable.of(this.build()))`. It works but `map()` is cleaner. I still wonder why exactly the error was thrown.

Comment: *"I still wonder why exactly the error was thrown."* Because `this.build(elemTag)`, *as both answers and my comment have told you*, gets called to create the observable to pass to `.concat`. `.switchMap(() => Observable.of(thing))` (or `.flatMap(...)`) is equivalent to `.map(() => thing)`, you don't need to wrap the value yourself.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe

Comment: Also, you could simplify by not making `rendererSet$` a `BehaviourSubject`, and only pushing something into it when a *non-null* renderer is set; then you won't need to `.filter(...)`. If you want late subscribers to receive the last valid renderer, try `ReplaySubject`, but the vanilla `Subject` will probably suffice.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do want late subscribers to receive the output immediately. I will try ReplaySubject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `this.build(elemTag)` is called when composing the `concat` observable - not when the concatenation is performed.

You could solve the problem using [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer):

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/defer';

...
return Observable.concat(
  this.rendererSet$.filter(e => !!e).take(1),
  Observable.defer(() => Observable.of(this.build(elemTag)))
);
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments, using `map`:

```
return this.rendererSet$
  .filter(e => !!e)
  .take(1)
  .map(() => this.build(elemTag));
```

Comment: Didn't know about `.defer()`. Thanks  I'll look it up. I think I'll use `mapTo()` since I don't care about the output of the first observable beyond knowing that the Renderer has been set. Your answer was also the first to get me to understand why the error was thrown.

Comment: I see you've edited your answer. `.mapTo(this.build())` throws the error. I guess it executes immediately. `.map()` it is.

Comment: Yep. I didn't think that one through.

Answer (score -1):

It is because, you create an Observable of whatever `this.build` function returns. Since, you haven't set the renderer yet, the line below throws an error. Make sure you
call `setRenderer` function first

```
if (!this.renderer) 
    throw new Error('Renderer must be set before build() is run');
```

You should be able to solve this by returning an Observable as follows

```
return Observable.concat(
  this.rendererSet$.filter(e=>!!e).take(1),
  this.rendererSet$.asObservable().map(() => this.build(elemTag)) // this line will execute when there is a new value set to rendererSet
)
```

Comment: *"Make sure you call `setRenderer` function first"* isn't terribly helpful advice when that's precisely what the OP is *trying* to do.

Comment: This would explain why calling `build()` directly would error. But `safeBuild()` tries to solve this by waiting for `setRenderer()` before calling `build()`. My question is, why does running `safeBuild()` also error?

Comment: He said ` later -- after safeBuild(), and from another component.`. I'm saying that he should call it first.